# Scipy construct a network graph from text file

Tags: python, numpy, graph, scipy

I have the following data that represents a graph in a text file:

```
     a,b,1
     a,c,2
     b,c,1
     etc..
```

I need to build a matrix representation of this graph using SciPy.
Right now, I read everything in a dictionary:

```
graph = { "a" : [("b",1), ("c",2)],
          "b" : [("b",1)]
        }
```

My question is how to move from a dictionary to an numpy array. Or if there is anyway to read directly from the text file into a numpy array using numpy.loadtxt()?

**Edit**

Desired format is a scipy csr_matrix representing the graph:

```
  a b c
a 0 1 2
b 0 0 1
c 0 0 0
```

Comment: You could do this with pandas using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and [as_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert a dict to an numpy array you can easily use:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array(list(graph.items()))
```

i couldn't try it but i hope it can helps you

Answer (score 0):

To convert a dictionary to a dataframe of the form

```
  a b c
a 0 1 2
b 0 0 1
c 0 0 0
```

you can give a properly formed dictionary to the constructor. It accepts a dictionary.

```
graph = { "a" : [0, 0, 0],
          "b" : [1, 0, 0],
          "c" : [2, 1, 0]
        }

import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame(graph)
```

Also, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146892/numpy-scipy-build-adjacency-matrix-from-weighted-edgelist) for an example of how to convert an edge list to an adjacency matrix:

Comment: the challenge then becomes, how to generate the properly formatted dictionary based on the text file.