# Create sparse indicator matrix for column pairs

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns.  I would like to create a sparse indicator matrix for pairs in those two columns (scipy.sparse.csr_matrix or cipy.sparse.csc_matrix).

The data is large so pandas functions cannot be used to widen the shape.  What I would like to go from and to is as follows:

From:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1,2], [2,2], [3,6], [3, 5])), columns = ['A', 'B'])
df

    A   B
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   6
3   3   5
```

To:

```
df['ones'] = 1
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['A'], columns = ['B'], values = ['ones'])
pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel()
pivoted

B   2   5   6
A           
1   1.0 NaN NaN
2   1.0 NaN NaN
3   NaN 1.0 1.0
```

This comes close: [numpy/scipy build adjacency matrix from weighted edgelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146892/numpy-scipy-build-adjacency-matrix-from-weighted-edgelist) but I would like to know how I do this with an unweighted graph (i.e. two columns rather than three)

I have been googling and playing around with numpy arrays to get there but it has officially taken too long now.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach now?

Comment: @Quang Hoang - The data is huge.  I need to create the adjacency matrix more efficiently.  I will be then doing some dot product operations with the adjacency matrix, so igraph doesn't help.  So the result needs to be sparse, but also, I can't use pandas to get there or I will run out of memory the moment I try to pivot.

Comment: I think what I need is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146892/numpy-scipy-build-adjacency-matrix-from-weighted-edgelist but I would like to know how I do this with an unweighted graph (i.e. two columns rather than three)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
csc = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones_like(df['A']), (df['A'],df['B'])))

csc.toarray()
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Great, yes, that will work.  What about the case where you don't have continuous IDs?  i.e. A = [1,6099877734, 50].  I suppose it doesn't matter for a sparse representation? i.e. we are not actually creating a matrix with 6099877734 rows.

Comment: Yes, but you still creating a sparse matrix, so it shouldn't be causing you many more memory.